# Mysql str_to_date () return NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a string `'10/01/2016 00:00'` that I want convert to DATETIME

I tried like this:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('10/01/2016 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i');
```

But it's not working. what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `%h` expects an hour in the format 01-12 and you are providing an hour that is 00. You can use `%H` that expects an hour in the format 00-23, try with this:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('10/01/2016 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```